How can I calculate the value of L and C for a boost converter operating in DCM mode?
I already know that the value of the inductor for a DCM mode should be any which is smaller than the value required for critical conduction but out of the range. How could I decide which value would be optimum for the circuit? I only need a mathematical analysis over the selection before I go for any designing. For the capacitor, how can one find the value? In CCM, the ripple criteria helps in finding out the value. What logic can one use for the DCM?

How much peak current can your transistor and diode handle? How much voltage ripple can you accept for a capacitor which mechanically fits your design (both capacitance and ESR)?

Have you tried simulating a simple ideal boost converter to get a better understanding of things?


I only need a mathematical analysis over the selection

I will not give you full formulae but what you can do is, basically, calculate an inductance value for CrCM (critical or boundary mode operation) for the extreme case which is when the input voltage is minimum and the output power is maximum, assuming for a constant output voltage (Note that the output voltage will still depend on the duty-cycle only so the calculation is easier with volt-seconds balance). Any smaller inductance than this will guarantee DCM over the entire input voltage and output power range.

how could I decide which value would be optimum for the circuit.

"Optimum" has different meaning for different situations. Quite a few things such as cost, size, thermal performance etc should be considered.
Since you want DCM operation, the inductor ripple current will be quite large (note that the average value of the inductor current is the DC input current). So, despite the fact that a smaller inductance generally means smaller DC resistance, you still can face an excessive loss due to the high ripple currents. Also, you must select an inductor that should NOT saturate with these high peak currents.

For capacitor, how can one find the value? In CCM, the ripple criteria helps in finding out the value, what logic can one use for the DCM?

Same logic because the inductor ripple current will flow through the output capacitor. One important thing here is that the ripple current is way higher in DCM compared to that in CCM. So, apart from the output voltage ripple requirement, the output capacitor should be able to handle the high ripple currents. This may result in either a physically large or quite a few number of paralleled capacitors.
